# Recordsestclone; not a valid bookmark

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to copy a record from subform, FrmEmergencyContactSub and insert it into another subform FrmWidowSub.

```
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim rsMember As DAO.Recordset
        
        strCriteria = "Members_FID = " & Me![Member_ID]
        Set rsMember = Me.FrmEmergencyContactSub.Form.RecordsetClone
        rsMember.FindFirst strCriteria
    
    If rsMember.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "No match found"
    Else
        Me.FrmWidowSub.Form.Bookmark = rsMember.Bookmark
    End If
```

I've come up with this: however, I get an error, not a valid bookmark.  I'm not sure of the syntax of the Me.FrmWidowSub.Form.Bookmark.  The "Form.Bookmark property (Access)" help page has the syntax as  Me.Bookmark. If I change the code above to that, then I don't get an error, nothing happens. I've tried many different iterations to get to the subform for the bookmark, but can't seem to get the correct syntax.

D

Answer (score 0):

The bookmark must be used on the same recordset. Try:

```vb
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim rsSource As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsTarget As DAO.Recordset
        
strCriteria = "Members_FID = " & Me![Member_ID]
Set rsSource = Me!FrmEmergencyContactSub.Form.RecordsetClone
rsSource.FindFirst strCriteria
    
If rsSource.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "No match found"
Else
    Set rsTarget = Me!FrmWidowSub.Form.RecordsetClone
    rsTarget.AddNew
        '
        ' Copy the fields.
        '
    rsTarget.Update
    ' Go to the new record.
    rsTarget.MoveLast
    ' Move the subform to the new record.
    Me.FrmWidowSub.Form.Bookmark = rsTarget.Bookmark
End If

rsTarget.Close
rsSource.Close
```

Comment: I'm now getting a no current record on the same line, Me.FrmWidowSub.Form.Bookmark = rsTarget.Bookmark

Comment: You may need to move to the last record. See extended answer, please.